# Can someone explain whether $C^{\infty}(M)$ is an algebra or a commutative ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, differential-geometry

One forms $\Omega^1(M)$ is a module over $C^{\infty}(M)$, therefore does that make $C^{\infty}(M)$ an algebra or a commutative ring?

Answer (score 3):

If $R$ is a commutative ring, we say that a commutative ring $S$ equipped with a ring homomorphism $R\to S$ is an "algebra" over $R$, or just an $R$-algebra for brevity.

Thus, there is no inconsistency in saying that $C^\infty(M)$ is **both** a commutative ring, and an $\mathbb{R}$-algebra (where $\mathbb{R}$ denotes the ring of real numbers, and the homomorphism $\mathbb{R}\to C^\infty(M)$ sends a real number $a$ to the constant function $c_a:M\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $c_a(x)=a$ for all $x\in M$).